# Is there any funding opportunity for postdoc in US?

Tags: funding, postdocs

I have a friend from Singapore who are interested in doing postdoc in US but have found no desired profs wanting him, since his research does not match those professors that he would like to work with. Therefore, he is looking other general funding opportunity that allows he to be funded so that he can work with prof in US if possible.

He is very good in research, and has published quite a few topics in top conferences and a journal. But to perform new research that matches those profs need 1-2 years. Therefore, he is looking  for funding like
http://www.society-in-science.org
that could grant him work with other professors (prof don't need to give money).

Hope that someone could shed him some light,  either

1. Possible methods that address his problem (not spending another 2 years for performing those related research - but you can assume he has really good capability in doing those research independently, it just that you cannot see it from his current publication history)
2. funding opportunity that are available;

Comment: Question edited

Comment: The edit provides a lot of additional information, but I'm still not sure it's a good fit for this site, since any answer seems like it will necessarily depend very much on your friend's situation and not be generalizable to others.

Answer (score 4):

NSF funds hundreds of postdocs through grants to professors and direct grants to postdocs themselves. As long as you are physically in the US, there's usually no limitation that the money must go to US citizens.

Comment: NSF postdocs are not available to internationals. See the example for SEES postdocs FAQ [link] (https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/2011/nsf11088/nsf11088.jsp)
"Applicants must be U. S. citizens or nationals, or permanent residents of the United States by the application deadline. " This was also the Advice given to me by the NSF Earth Sciences staff. 
The regular NSF grants, project grants, can go to anyone but then you need to have a position as they generally only cover a small amount of the PI's salary.